# Join and group by ouput as single array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, join

Is there any way to join tables and group results as single array using single query using mysql and sql server

Suppose i have two tables user and user_jobs

user:

```
user_id   username
-------  ----------
 1        user1
 2        user2
```

user_jobs:

```
user_id  job   place designation
 ------  ---- ------ ---

1         job1    p1     d1
1         job2    p2     d2
1         job3    p3     d3

select * from user join user_jobs on user.user_id = user_jobs.user_id
```

I will get three rows for the query result.Is there anyway to join these tables and output the result as one array?

Expected Output:-

```
[
  username:user1,
  user_id:1,
  job:array(jobs),
  place:array(place),
  designation:array(designation)
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using GROUP_CONCAT like this and turn that result (a comma separated list into array) using php `explode`.

```
select user.username,user.user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(job) as jobs,
       GROUP_CONCAT(place) as place,
       GROUP_CONCAT(designation) as designation 
from user join user_jobs on user.user_id = user_jobs.user_id
GROUP BY user_id,user_name
```

UDPATE: 
If thought this question had a mysql tag... I guess not
If you're using SQL Server,
You can try

```
SELECT user.username,user.user_id,
       job, place, designation
from user join user_jobs on user.user_id = user_jobs.user_id
ORDER BY user.username,user.user_id
```

and then in php have it loop through the returned resultset building the arrays for job,place,designation detecting when a user_id changes to create a new user

Comment: group_concat works only in mysql, how about in sql server.thanks

Comment: updated my answer, sorry not that familiar with sql server.